# Unable to compare values from alert dialog edit text and my string

Tags: java, android

```
regsCode1=objCommonServices.fetchRegisterationCode(etMobileNo.getText().toString().trim(),etPassword.getText().toString().trim());
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Recharhge Confirmation");
alert.setMessage("Message");
// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Editable value = input.getText();
            System.out.println("Hello"+regsCode1 +" Value is "+value.toString());
            if(value.toString().equals(regsCode1)){
                System.out.println("Hello"+regsCode1+" "+value);
            }
             else{
                System.out.println("B");
            }
        }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           // Canceled.
      }
});
alert.show();
```

I get the result B. Since System.out print both values correctly but it doesn't compare two strings
I have even changed Editable value from String value and used toString fn of object class. but then also i can't compare two values

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of case?

Comment: try if(value.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(regsCode1))

Comment: No problem of case i checked it.Is there file data/anr/stacktraces.txt problem

Comment: +1 for not being `==` vs `euqlas()` question.

Comment: I am really surprised with this stuff

Answer (score 1):

Compare like this

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
   String value = input.getText().toString().trim(); /// use this line 
   System.out.println("Hello"+regsCode1 +" Value is "+value);
      if(value.equals(regsCode1)){
         System.out.println("Hello"+regsCode1+" "+value);
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("B");
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `if(value.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(regsCode1))`

Comment: It if(value.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(regsCode1)) doesn't work.

Comment: can you please paste the values you are passing in variable value and regsCode1

Comment: F9D9378E  both regsCode1 & value hold this